# Which kind of layout to use for creating complex forms on an Android tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet

We are creating a complex forms-based application for entering business data on an Android tablet. The minimum available space will be round 400x500dp, but could easily be larger. A typical 7" tablet is around 600x960dp. We expect to have at least 15 fields on a form, but could be 20 or more.

The design consists mainly of textual labels and fields, with some buttons and the odd image. It places a high priority on vertical alignment of elements and meaningful grouping of fields.

The problem is what kind of Layout to choose. In summary:

- RelativeLayout allows precise location of View elements, at the cost of being tied to a specific size of screen, because the elements are placed at the dp level.
- GridLayout might improve on this by allowing elements to be placed at the grid cell level, and those cells could be resized from one screen size to another.
- TableLayout corresponds to a similar concept in HTML, which is used successfully for web forms, but depends to produce rather fluid results.

We rejected simply LinearLayouts because of insufficient control over positioning and vertical alignment, and the need for complex nested layouts.

I could post some XML code, but I doubt it would help. Currently we have RelativeLayout and lots of widgets at fixed offsets, and that's all it would show. We're looking for a better solution.

So, which kind of layout is best for creating business forms on an Android tablet?

Answer (score 0):

I would use LinearLayouts. If you can set them properly, they can size themselves quite well.

-You should use weights with them.

-Inner layouts and widgets could be match parent to weighted layouts.

-Use gravity to precise their location.

-Dont forget "gravity" just tells to CHILDREN where they should stay and "layout_gravity" says tell to parent where it should be.